# Gridview or listview show image above data

Tags: wpf, image, listview, gridview

I have some data contained on a generic collection of Entity. This entity contain an ImageName and an ImagePath property which is used to group data. Sometime there is an Image sometime not and I would like to show image above related rows just like in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM69s.png) mock up. In [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM69s.png) example it is a RadGridView but it seem's that can't be done with that grid so i'm looking for another option.

Comment: It *can* be done with either that or any other collection control. You need to investigate [`DataTemplate`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [`ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx), but don't expect others to do all your work for you. On this website, you need to show that you've made an effort to achieve your own requirements.

Comment: English isn't my first language and I don't master it yet... May be I sounded  like a lazy guy looking for someone who would write the whole code for him but that was not my goal  when I posted my question on this site. I am looking for a solution for this since over a week googling "gridview image group header" and things like that... May be to you it will sound stupid but I didn't know exactly what I was looking for. Why am I looking for solution in English? Because in my language there is nearly no support for programmers. But thanks you just gave me what I needed

Comment: Your English is good enough to understand and no I didn't think you were lazy... I was just informing you of some of the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on this website. And no, it doesn't sound stupid either - this website is used all over the world. So welcome to Stack Overflow and I'm glad I could point you in the right direction.